# applying bounce animation to div elements manually using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

Here, I am trying to apply bounce animation to my dynamically generated messages called by `API` but no effect is coming. Also, I tried using `effect()` but it was also of no use. Here is the link to my `Codepen`. [Link](http://codepen.io/asinha/pen/mRNzJj)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#getMessage").on("click",function () {
        //(".message").effect("bounce", {times:300}, 300);  
        move();
    });    

    var divObj = null;

    function init () {
        divObj = document.getElementById("message");
        //   $("#message").toggle("bounce", {times: 6}, "slow"); 
        divObj.style.position = "relative";
        divObj.style.top = "0px";
    }

    function move () {
        divObj.style.top = parseInt(divObj.style.top) + 10 + "px";
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks @elchininet for the edit suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've supplied above isn't too far off from the result(s) you're looking for. Essentially the `{times:300}` you are supplying is far too many for the speed/ratio - resulting in no ***visible*** animation.

From what I have just tested, any ***bounces >10*** with the ***speed @300*** seem to display in an abnormal manner.

***Please see this codepen:*** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWyqpY

Give this a try:

```
$("#getMessage").on("click",function () {
    $(".message").effect("bounce",{times:3},300);

    // I'm not sure if you still want this method.
    move();
});
```

Comment: Please go to the codepen I just supplied in my edit. This seems to be actively working from what you've supplied.

Comment: thanks!! it worked. Do you know what's the issue with the manual animation though

Comment: @aayushi awesome, I'm glad it worked! Also, what do you mean about the manual animation?

Comment: i mean with the function move().